# Trouble with Rock-Paper-Scissors

Tags: c++

I've been working on a project for school, making a rock-paper-scissors game using functions. This is the code I have so far, but the program is having some problems. This is what the program is returning right now.

```
Rock, Paper, Scissors

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Rock: 1

Paper: 2

Scissors: 3

2

You picked:

Computer picked:



Press any key to continue . . .
```

It is not displaying any of the strings, and I don't know enough about the language to figure out why :( I would appreciate some help/pointers/fixes on the code. I'm not using std namespace because a guide I found suggested that it might be causing the issue.

```
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string GetComputerChoice(std::string ComputerChoice)
{
   double Computer;
   Computer = rand() % 3 + 1;

   if (Computer == 1)
   {
      ComputerChoice == "rock";
      return ComputerChoice;
   }
   else if (Computer == 2)
   {
      ComputerChoice == "paper";
      return ComputerChoice;
   }
   else
   {
      ComputerChoice == "scissors";
      return ComputerChoice;
   }
}

std::string GetUserChoice(std::string UserChoice)
{
   double User;
   std::cin >> User;

   if (User < 1 || User > 3)
   {
      std::cout << "Invalid entry ";
      system("pause");
      return 0;
   }
   else if (User = 1)
   {
      UserChoice == "rock";
      return UserChoice;
   }
   else if (User = 2)
   {
      UserChoice == "paper";
      return UserChoice;
   }
   else
   {
      UserChoice == "scissors";
      return UserChoice;
   }
}

std::string DetermineWinner( std::string UserChoice, std::string ComputerChoice, std::string Victory )
{
   Victory == "Something Has Gone Wrong";

   if (ComputerChoice == UserChoice)
   {
      Victory == "Tie!";
      return Victory;
   }
   else if (UserChoice == "rock")
   {
      if (ComputerChoice == "paper")
      {
         Victory == "Paper beats rock! You lose!";
         return Victory;
      }
      else
      {
         Victory == "Rock smashes scissors! You win!";
         return Victory;
      }
   }
   else if (UserChoice == "paper")
   {
      if (ComputerChoice == "rock")
      {
         Victory == "Paper beats rock! You win!";
         return Victory;
      }
      else
      {
         Victory == "Scissors cut paper! You lose!";
         return Victory;
      }
   }
   else
   {
      if (ComputerChoice == "paper")
      {
         Victory == "Scissors cut paper! You win!";
         return Victory;
      }
      else
      {
         Victory == "Rock smashes scissors! You lose!";
         return Victory;
      }
   }
}

int main()
{
   std::cout << "Rock, Paper, Scissors" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Rock: 1" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Paper: 2" << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Scissors: 3" << std::endl;

   std::string UserChoice, ComputerChoice, Victory;

   GetUserChoice( UserChoice );
   GetComputerChoice( ComputerChoice );
   DetermineWinner( UserChoice, ComputerChoice, Victory);

   std::cout << "You picked: " << UserChoice << std::endl;
   std::cout << "Computer picked: " << ComputerChoice << std::endl;
   std::cout << Victory << std::endl;
   system("pause");
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't reassign the arguments to the function like that. You need to use the return value of `GetUserChoice` instead. Get rid of the parameter to the `Get` functions, since it isn't doing anything, and reassign instead assign the return value from the function to the variable:

```
UserChoice = GetUserChoice();
```

As a side note, please look up proper naming conversations. Arbitrary variable names shouldn't be capitalized like that. Capitalized identifiers are reserved primarily for class names.

Comment: Well you can assign them, but it wont have the effect the OP suspected.

An alternative would be to pass the argument by reference.

Comment: This is the simplest answer, alternatively the OP should look up the difference between pass-by-value and pass-by-reference for function parameters

Comment: I agree with both, but why would you ever try to change a parameter when you can just return the value?

Comment: Also you should use == for comparison and = for assignment, and returning 0 in GetUserChoice for invalid will usually crash, return a string instead.

Comment: Actually, my C++ is exceedingly rusty, but with an immutable object, even passing by reference wouldn't allow what they're trying to do. Reassigning the reference in the function would do just that: reassign the local reference. Unless I'm missing something. If the object was mutable, than ya, that would work.

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple issues:

1. You're incorrectly comparing strings when you should be assigning them:

   ```
   ComputerChoice == "rock";
   ```

   To assign `"rock"` to `ComputerChoice`, make sure you use `=`:

   ```
   ComputerChoice = "rock";
   ```
2. You return the computer's choice with `return ComputerChoice;`, but you never save that returned value when calling `GetComputerChoice()`:

   ```
   GetComputerChoice( ComputerChoice );
   ```

   Instead, you'll have to write it as:

   ```
   ComputerChoice = GetComputerChoice();
   ```

   Notice that you don't need to pass anything into the function; you can remove `std::string ComputerChoice` as a function parameter.

Of course, the two examples above aren't the only places in your code that're incorrect; you'll have to go through and fix any part of your code that hits one of the above issues.